# AssetBundle not working properly

Tags: unity, c#

I am using Unity 5.0.1.  I have created the asset bundle of a sprite by selecting the name "img.unity3D" from the dropdown and then running the script :

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles ("AssetBundles");
```

It successfully creates the "img.unity3D" file and "img.unity3D.manifest" file for that sprite in AssetBundles directory.

Now, I am uploading the "img.unity3D" to my server and trying to download it through :

```
 WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(URL, 0);
```

as I need to save the image on the local storage also.  When I am trying to get the main asset from the asset bundle and casting it as sprite, its returning null.

```
AssetBundle imageBundle = www.assetBundle;
testSprite.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = imageBundle.mainAsset as Sprite;
```

But, it doesn't seem to work.

1. Am I uploading the right file "img.unity3d" or I also need to upload .manifest file on to the server.
2. Is there any thing that I am missing, because I tried uploading only sprite and tried to download it, I was able to cast that to a sprite but not the case with assetbundle.

Sorry for such a long post...!!!

Comment: You absolutely don't need the manifest, though in this case I'd recommend storing the bundle's hash somehow. You see how you're passing 0 to LoadFromCacheOrDownload? LoadFromCacheOrDownload will only redownload the bundle if that value has changed. This means you'll always be using the first ever uploaded bundle no matter how much it's changed. So if you uploaded a faulty version before, that's probably your problem. Something else to try is using LoadAsset instead of mainAsset.

Comment: @Ben : Thanks for the reply.  I have tried LoadAsset also, but it didn't work.  From the first attempt only, its not working, so I think it might not be related to version number as well. Any other possibility that you can think of ??

Comment: Just to make sure, try changing the version number. Another problem may be the asset bundle's name. Try changing it to something that doesn't contain a period( periods are used to specify asset bundle variants, so it may be interfering somehow )